# How to apply this code in n-dimension using R?

Tags: r

Under R I developed this script:

```
Sphere_1 = function (x1,x2) return(x1^2+x2^2)  #sphere function / objective function 
    
Initial_search_domain_function <- function(N,p,MIN_t_x,MAX_t_x,MIN_t_y,MAX_t_y , Objfun=custom_fun ) { 
  x1 <- runif(N, min = MIN_t_x, max = MAX_t_x)                               # Create x vector (same as in Example 1 & 2)
  y1 <- runif(N, min = MIN_t_y, max = MAX_t_y)                                 # Create y vector (same as in Example 2)

  m <- outer(x1, y1, Objfun) #matrix of minimum objective values

  print("matrix of objective function")
  #print(m)

  p_minimum_value <- sort(m)[1:p]    # search p minimum values of the objective function 'Objfun' within m 
  X_Y_indices=which(relist(m %in% p_minimum_value, m), arr.ind = TRUE) # retrieve their corresponding row/cloumn at m 
  #print(X_Y_indices)
  print("list of respective positions")
  v1=x1[X_Y_indices[,1]]  # retrieve their corresponding x-coordinate from x1 list 
  v2=y1[X_Y_indices[,2]]  # retrieve their corresponding y-coordinate from y1 list 
  
  respective_positions=rbind(v1,v2)  # store those coordinate in a matrix 
  respective_positions=rbind(respective_positions, `fun(x, y)` = apply(respective_positions, 2, function(x) Objfun(x[1], x[2])))
  # compute the objective function for each row
  rownames(respective_positions)=c("x:","y:","obj-val")
  print(respective_positions)
  return(respective_positions)
  
}
```

Example of output:

```
Initial_search_domain_function(40,5,-4.5,4.5,-4.5,4.5, Sphere_1 )  ;

[1] "matrix of objective function"
[1] "list of respective positions"
             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]
x:      0.2904639 0.29046393 0.29046393 -0.40499210 0.29046393
y:      0.2894644 0.07744045 0.05273694  0.05273694 0.11452047
obj-val 0.1681589 0.09036632 0.08715048  0.16679979 0.09748423
```

I'm wanting a way such that the code not only work for a two-variables function f(x,y) , but also for n-dimensions function.

For example if n=3 I could get something like:

```
[1] "list of respective positions"
             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]
x:      0.2904639 0.29046393 0.29046393 -0.40499210 0.29046393
y:      0.2894644 0.07744045 0.05273694  0.05273694 0.11452047
z:      0.2904639 0.27046393 0.50046393 -0.90499210 0.129046393
obj-val 0.1681589 0.09036632 0.08715048  0.16679979 0.09748423
```

with n-dimensional function like:

```
Sphere = function (x) return(sum(x^2))  #sphere function / objective function
```

The main problem is that I don't know how to compute Cartesian products for n-sets with their respective objective function values  f (X) where X is n-dimensional.

Comment: to ensure your work is reproducible. Can you set a seed?

Comment: @ Onyambu , I think what's the code do is clear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an p-dimensional function. Note that this is just an exact replica of your code, only made to work for `p-dimensions`. Notice that I gave it a seed argument in order for one to make comparisons:

```
Sphere_1_pdim = function (x) return(sum(x^2))  
Initial_search_domain_function_pdim <- function(N, p, MIN, MAX, Objfun, seed = NULL) { 
  
  stopifnot(length(MIN) == length(MAX),length(N) == 1,length(p) == 1)
  dims <- numeric(length(MIN)) + N
  set.seed(seed)
  X <- Map(runif,N,MIN,MAX)
  names(X) <- paste0("X",seq_along(X),":") 
  m <- array(apply(expand.grid(X),1,Objfun), dims)
  p_minimum_value <- sort(m)[1:p]
  indices <-which(array(m %in% p_minimum_value, dim(m)), arr.ind = TRUE)
  
  t(cbind(mapply("[",X,data.frame(indices)),"obj-val:" = m[indices]))
}

Initial_search_domain_function_pdim(40, 5, c(-4.5,-4.5,-4.5), c(4.5,4.5,4.5), Sphere_1_pdim, 0)
                [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
X1:      -0.02070682 -0.02070682 -0.05812824 -0.02070682 -0.05812824
X2:      -0.20142340  0.16770837  0.16770837 -0.19309277 -0.19309277
X3:      -0.19693769 -0.19693769 -0.19693769 -0.19693769 -0.19693769
obj-val:  0.07978461  0.06733932  0.07028944  0.07649804  0.07944816
```

Your code output:

```
Initial_search_domain_function(40,5, -4.5, 4.5, -4.5, 4.5, Sphere_1, 0)
               [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
x:      -0.02070682 -0.02070682 -0.05812824 -0.02070682 -0.05812824
y:      -0.20142340  0.16770837  0.16770837 -0.19309277 -0.19309277
obj-val  0.04100016  0.02855487  0.03150499  0.03771359  0.04066371
```